# How to remove an application that doesn't show up in Finder, but is listed in System Information?

Tags: finder, software, macos

I want to uninstall the `ConnectWiseControl Client`, located in the `Downloads` folder, as shown by `System Profiler`:

[image: ra]

This app doesn't show up in `Applications`, and if I try to delete the app manually, by removing it from `Downloads` folder, it stays listed in `System Profiler`.

How can I safely delete the `ConnectWiseControl Client`, so that all traces of it are gone?

Comment: First, contact the company concerned - https://docs.connectwise.com/ConnectWise_Control_Documentation/Get_started/Knowledge_base/Manually_remove_an_access_agent

Comment: There is no generic way?

Comment: No, because there is no 'generic' installer method. When it was installed, it will have asked for Admin perms, which would allow it to write to system folders. Short of scavenging for remnants, which may not all share the same name, then once you've thrown out the main app, you have no real trace on what went where. Usually apps that install that way are either uninstalled from within the app, or by script.

Answer (score 1):

System Information does continue to list apps, even if they've been removed. (Even after a refresh with Command R.)

If you've checked that the application is not at the filepath listed, then don't worry.